# inflection points of a projective curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

Let $C \subset \mathbb{P}^2$ be a non singular  projective curve of degree $d$. Assume base field is $\mathbb{C}$. Does there always exist a point $x \in C$ such that intersection multiplicity of tangent line-$T_x$- at $x$ is $d$.

This is vacuously true if $d=2$, the case of conics. When $d=3$, Elliptic curves also have 3-torsion points, in fact 9 of them. Is this always true for higher degrees?

Edit: Given $d \geq 4$ there always exist curves without any points having intersection multiplicity greater than 3. Here's a sketch of the argument. One starts by comparing the dimension of the space of all degree $d$ curves in $\mathbb{P}^2$ (which is $\mathbb{P}^N,N = {d+2\choose 2}-1$) and the closed subscheme of all degree $d$ curves having the required property. The codimension of closed subscheme will atleast be 1.